# Parallel axis theorem non-uniform density

Tags: torque, rotation, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

The parallel axis theorem says that if the moment of inertia of a body rotating about the body's centre of mass is $I_{cm}$, then the moment of inertia of the body rotating about an axis parallel to the original axis and displaced from it a distance $d$ is $I_{S}=I_{cm}+Md^2$, where $M$ is the body's mass.

I know for a fact that this applies in cases of uniform density. Does this same theorem apply if the body's density is *not* uniform?

Comment: Yes, it does. Have a look at the proof, it doesn't assume anything about the mass distribution.

Comment: Have you looked at [how the parallel axis theorem is derived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem#Derivation)? From this the answer should be obvious.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)