# Are the parallel and perpendicular axes theorem for determination of moment of inertia valid only for bodies of uniform mass density?

Tags: moment-of-inertia

Are the parallel and perpendicular axes theorem for determination of moment of inertia valid only for bodies of uniform mass density?

Answer (score 1):

No. These theorems apply for any mass distribution - continuous, discrete, uniform density, non-uniform density. See derivations in wikipedia for [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem#Derivation) and [perpendicular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_axis_theorem) theorems. Note that density does not enter into the derivation, and no assumption of uniform mass distribution is made.

Comment: I read [Parallel axis theorem non-uniform density](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229051) and intially answered that question by mistake!